# Exchange Powershell - Check if a user is in a specific mailbox database

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to writing a script to move a user to a new database and then export their  mailbox to pst, but I need to verify if the user is in the correct database to begin with from a user input.

I am trying a command like:

```
Get-Mailbox -Database "Archive Mailbox Database" -Identity Fbloggs
```

Then I would error trap if the user is not found. This line does not work however with error:

```
Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Get-Mailbox
```

Many thanks for any help.

NA

Comment: Does the cmdlet work if you drop the -database argument?

Answer (score 2):

Try with the Filter parameter (you can also use Name instead of Alias):

```
Get-Mailbox -Database "Archive Mailbox Database" -Filter {Alias -eq 'Fbloggs'}
```

Or the other way around:

```
(Get-Mailbox -Identity Fbloggs).Database.Name
```

Or

```
Get-Mailbox -Database "Archive Mailbox Database" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Fbloggs'}
```

Comment: This does not seem to limit the query to the specific database.

Comment: I added another example. The second example tells you the db of the user mailbox and the third checks if the mailbox is a part of the specified database.

Comment: You can't use -database and -filter in conjunctions.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123685.aspx

Comment: @arcass I just did and it worked (Exchange 2010), do you get an error? Take a look at the fourth syntax item in the url you posted